# Looping Duplicate Records in R

Tags: r

I have the Following table(Results df):

```
FN            DC     ACC    CC  IND
20140926-1284   552 75.05%  2232    CMC1
20140926-1286   554 50.59%  2245    CMC1
20140926-1286   552 50.64%  2232    CMC1
20140926-1299   552 58.03%  2232    CMC1
20140926-1299   554 74.53%  2254    CMC1
20140926-1300   556 68.17%  2276    CMC1
20140926-1300   552 57.31%  2232    CMC1
20140926-1301   556 68.17%  2276    CMC1
20140926-1301   552 57.31%  2232    CMC1
20140926-1301   554 74.53%  2254    CMC1
20140926-1302   556 58.17%  2276    CMC1
20140926-1302   552 57.31%  2232    CMC1
20140926-1302   554 74.53%  2254    CMC1
```

For those feedback numbers that are repeated (duplicates) - I need to check for `ACC` column and if the difference in the
`ACC` column is less than 10% - then assign null(20140926-1286 -> 50.64-50.59=0.05), if  the difference in the `ACC` column is greater than 10% then assign the largest value. So that

My output result should be:

```
FN              DC       ACC      CC     IND
20140926-1284   552   75.05%    2232    CMC1
20140926-1286   null    null    null    null
20140926-1299   554   74.53%    2254    CMC1
20140926-1300   556   68.17%    2276    CMC1
20140926-1301   null    null    null    null
20140926-1302   554   74.53%    2254    CMC1
```

**Update:**

I have created unique and duplicate records as separate dataframe -  using:

```
mylist <- split(Results, duplicated(Results$FN) | duplicated(Results$FN, fromLast = TRUE))
names(mylist) <- c("nodupe", "dupe")
list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)
```

I face issues in looping Duplicate records, `null` meaning assigning Blank values when the `ACC` is less than 10% difference. Structure of my input looks like

```
 str(Results)
 'data.frame':  13 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ FN : Factor w/ 5 levels "20140926-1284",..: 4 5 2 3 1 2 1
  $ DC   : int  556 552 552 552 552 554 554
  $ ACC   : Factor w/ 7 levels "57.86%","95.3%",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  $ CC    : int  2276 2232 2232 2232 2232 2245 2245
  $ IND   : Factor w/ 1 level "CMC1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: So where is the R code you have tried> What is the problem you are facing? Stack Overflow ins't a site where you can just order up code for others to write for you. We try to help you with a specific programming problem. Do you not know how to find duplicates? Do you not how know to split a data.frame by those duplicates? Do you not know how to perform operations on data.frames or lists of data.frames? What's the structure of your input? Is the column with "%" a factor or character? Do you want the character "null" in the return, because you can't have a true `NULL` value, or do you mean `NA`?

Comment: I don't understand the way you compute the difference in `ACC`. What happens when you have 3 records with the same `FN`, are you subscribing each from last record, or are you subscribing them each from each? Or are you just checking the range between the smallest and the largest value? Your question is very unclear

Comment: Also, why in `20140926-1302` you took the last duplicate `ACC` value, but in `20140926-1300` you took the first? Your problem seems very easy to solve but your question just unclear and incosistent

Comment: for `20140926-1302` Acc is (74.53-57.31 and 74.53-58.17 , the difference is greater than 10%, so assigning the one with largest percentage) for `20140926-1300` the diff. is (68.17-57.31, greater than 10%) so assignning the FN with largest value.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I need to check the differece with each FN duplicates.

Comment: 1- You didn't mention in your question that you are taking the largest value of `ACC`. 2- In you comment above, you didn't compare each of `ACC` values, rather you compared all agains the largest (something you also didn't mention), `74.53` is the largest and you comparing only against it. You should include details like that in the original question in the first place. No one can guess that

Comment: Also, in `20140926-1301` 74.53 - 57.31 > 10, so why did you assign `NULL` to it?

Comment: for `20140926-1301 ` the Acc (74.53%-68.17%) DIDNT satisfy the condition

Comment: For `20140926-1301`, 74.53-57.31 = 17.22

Comment: @jazzurro  for `20140926-1301` the Acc (74.53%-68.17%) DIDNT satisfy the one condition, but the other 74.53-57.31 = 17.22 is matching, since - as one of them didnt satisfy , assigning null

Comment: So you want to make comparisons between the largest ACC and the rest, then. It would have been great, if you clarified that point in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an optional `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Results)[, ACC := as.numeric(as.character(gsub("%", "", ACC)))] # Converting ACC to numeric
Results[, .SD[unique(ifelse(.N > 1 & any((ACC[ACC == max(ACC)] - ACC[ACC != max(ACC)]) < 10), 
                         NA_integer_, 
                         which.max(ACC)))], by = FN]
#               FN  DC   ACC   CC  IND
# 1: 20140926-1284 552 75.05 2232 CMC1
# 2: 20140926-1286  NA    NA   NA   NA
# 3: 20140926-1299 554 74.53 2254 CMC1
# 4: 20140926-1300 556 68.17 2276 CMC1
# 5: 20140926-1301  NA    NA   NA   NA
# 6: 20140926-1302 554 74.53 2254 CMC1
```

Comment: for 20140926-1301 the Acc (74.53%-68.17%) DIDNT satisfy the one condition, but the other 74.53-57.31 = 17.22 is matching, since - as one of them didnt satisfy , assigning null

Comment: Ok, see my update. You should have include all of this information in the original question, rather us spending hours while trying to get it from you